# Use numeric custom metrics in Google Analytics on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I need to set a custom metric with a simple google analytics event.

I use the following method: to set the event, then set the custom metric, then send it all:

```
GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent(withCategory: <#T##String!#>, action: <#T##String!#>, label: <#T##String!#>, value: <#T##NSNumber!#>).set(<#T##value: String!##String!#>, forKey: <#T##String!#>).build()
```

But I need to pass an INT in parameter of the value of the custom metric, not a STRING. My custom metric is a numeric value.

I don't understand why I don't find any "set" function with an INT in value.

In practice:

```
let build = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent(withCategory: "cat", action: "act", label: "lab", value: nil).set("100", forKey: GAIFields.customMetric(for: 1)).build() as [NSObject : AnyObject]
GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker.send(build)
```

Result:

```
Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        "&_crc" = 0;
        "&_s" = 0;
        "&_u" = ".nteoyAL";
        "&_v" = "mi3.1.7";
        "&a" = 114102722;
        "&aid" = "com.dve.apptest";
        "&an" = PrizeeTestGA;
        "&av" = "1.0";
        "&cid" = "28c24faa-f546-43e6-b596-e5a1c4e61373";
        "&cm1" = 100;
        "&dm" = "x86_64";
        "&ds" = app;
        "&ea" = act;
        "&ec" = cat;
        "&el" = lab;
        "&ev" = "<null>";
        "&sr" = 750x1334;
        "&t" = event;
        "&tid" = "UA-108352-26";
        "&ul" = "en-us";
        "&v" = 1;
        "&z" = 17487374570739913012;
        gaiVersion = "3.17";
    };
    timestamp = "2016-10-14 10:02:38 +0000";
```

}

where "&cm1" = 100 as STRING...

Comment: and you cant just send cm1="100"  ?

Comment: but it will be considered as a String value?

Comment: No the server will convert it metrics must always be an int. However it's a rest API which eats strings. Its weird but give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed the server converts the String in Int. Obvious!